# Docker build showing invalid containerPort

Tags: node.js, docker

I need help in debugging this image build:
My dockerfile is :

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV PORT = 3000
RUN npm install
EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

and when I run `sudo docker build -t uddeshya/node1 .` to build the image, the log shows the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.009MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
 ---> dcda6cd5e439
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9450405b180f
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 91689830af35
Step 4/7 : ENV PORT = 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d99d55d0ae81
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dac4854ec168
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE $PORT
Invalid containerPort: =
```

The error point is at "EXPOSE $PORT", how do I fix this?

Comment: Try EXPOSE ${PORT} instead since it is docker and not the shell that has to do that particular extrapolation

Comment: For future people that have this error: I had it because I specified the command line parameter `-ip` instead of `--ip` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of ENV should be

```
ENV PORT=3000
```

That is the build throw error as it receives `=` because of spaces.

```
Step 3/6 : ENV PORT = 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8edc1281a96c
Step 4/6 : RUN echo ${PORT}
 ---> Running in 090a69369847
= 3000
```

without spaces it should be

```
Step 3/6 : ENV PORT=3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc29398a0ca6
Step 4/6 : RUN echo ${PORT}
 ---> Running in 9fc5d9b07342
3000
```

then yon can verify

```
docker inspect your_image
```

you can see

```
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3000/tcp": {}
            }
```